# Ways to access parrents data from member deque

Tags: c++, class, member, deque

Inside class `A` there is a deque of objects of class `B`. I have some common data in class `A` that I need to access from method of class `B`. What are the best ways to do it?

I know that I can pass that data as function parameters

```cpp
class B
{
    int compute(int a, int k);
};

class A
{
    void update()
    {
        deq[5].compute(a, k);
    }
};
```

But is there a better way to do it?

```cpp
class B
{
    int compute()
    {
        return A::i + A::k;
    }
};

class A
{
    std::deque<B> deq;
    int i;
    int k;
};
```

I expect to be able to acess class `A` data from member deque of class `B` without overhead of passing it through a function.

Comment: You need to tell the `B` instance which `A` instance to use in that case. Why do you think there's any noticable overhead? Have you measured it?

Comment: How to do that?